# MLC Chat app is crashing on LineageOS 18/Android 11

Tags: applications, crashes

I'm trying to use the [MLC Chat](https://mlc.ai/mlc-llm/#android) app. The language model is downloaded, the app starts, and when I send a message, everything drops!
I include the error log:

```
Process: ai.mlc.mlcchat
PID: 10194
UID: 10173
Flags: 0x20c8be44
Package: ai.mlc.mlcchat v1 (1.0)
Foreground: Yes
Process-Runtime: 25068
Build: samsung/greatltexx/dreamlte:8.0.0/R16NW/N950FXXU3CRC1:user/release-keys

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27 in ai.mlc.mlcchat:layout/user_message: Binary XML file line #27 in ai.mlc.mlcchat:layout/user_message: Error inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27 in ai.mlc.mlcchat:layout/user_message: Error inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
at ai.mlc.mlcchat.MessageAdapter.getView(MessageAdapter.java:72)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2387)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1417)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1323)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:763)
at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measure(BasicMeasure.java:426)
at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measureChildren(BasicMeasure.java:105)
at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:247)
at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:117)
at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1532)
at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1607)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:145)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:747)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3402)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2246)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2504)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1948)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8177)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7664)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable ai.mlc.mlcchat:drawable/user_rounded_corner with resource ID #0x7f0700dd
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/qo.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0700dd
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:891)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:673)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:993)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:1006)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:981)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5535)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1000)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:994)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:108)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:103)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
at ai.mlc.mlcchat.MessageAdapter.getView(MessageAdapter.java:72)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2387)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1417)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1323)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:763)
at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measure(BasicMeasure.java:426)
at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measureChildren(BasicMeasure.java:105)
at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:247)
at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:117)
at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1532)
at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1607)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:145)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:747)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3402)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2246)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2504)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1948)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8177)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7664)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to ComplexColor: type=0x1
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadComplexColorForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:1152)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadComplexColorFromName(ResourcesImpl.java:1028)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadColorStateList(ResourcesImpl.java:1107)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:1139)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:600)
at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.updateGradientDrawableStroke(GradientDrawable.java:1677)
at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.inflateChildElements(GradientDrawable.java:1589)
at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.inflate(GradientDrawable.java:1404)
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:144)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1402)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1361)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadXmlDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:954)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:877)
... 69 more
```

I don't understand much of the log, I really hope you can shed a little light, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. When it comes to app crashes we don't really have much of a resolution to offer because 1) often, the app's source code is not available for review and compilation; 2) suggesting changes to the code would be outside the scope of this site. Consider reporting the problem to the app's developer. If the developer says the problem is with the platform (Lineage OS) then report the problem with your ROM's maintainer.

Comment: Okay, thank you

Comment: @JohnFlamel looks like it's [a relatively known issue](https://github.com/mlc-ai/mlc-llm/issues/113). Please continue participating there because as Android end-users of Stack Exchange community, we can't really do anything about it here.

Comment: Okay,thanks ....